# How do I find the focal point for one lens in a double lens system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, visible-light, experimental-physics, lenses

[image]

So I'm trying to construct something that will use the two lens, (1) and (2) where lens 2 is 4x bigger than lens 1. The point of this thing will be to heat the small plate at the end of the cylinder thing, I've put everything in terms of a variable x but I get confused as to how I'm supposed to know the distance between where I place the two lens? How do I find the focal length of lens (2)??? I'm pretty confused and have been working on this for days but I can't figure it out I've tried looking at the calculations for telescopes and microscopes but I'm led into a big loop where I have 2 unknowns but only 1 equation. I understand that ideally having the focal point of lens 1 at the bottom of the barrel or pipe would be ideal but I want the energy input to the end plate to be a little spread out to promote a more equal heating of the plate. The equation I got where di2 = f2 makes sense but when I put it into formula 3 that just cancels out everything I need to know. Have I set up my system wrong? Whats happening here? I would put priority on the focal point being 2/3y down the barrel over keeping the height set at 6.5x if that's where I'm messing up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.